# Open a new window in tmux only if no window is opened in the given path, otherwise attach to it

Tags: tmux, pwd, terminal-multiplexer

Currently I have my terminal (`alacritty`) run `tmux new -A -s 0` at start to start a new session `0`, or attach to it if it already exists. One problem is, I sometimes use open in directory from file manager (Dolphin). In that case, I am just reconnected to the older session and not in the desired directory.

What I want to achieve is to open a new window in the session `0` with my desired path as working directory if no such window exists in the given session. Otherwise, I want to switch to that existing window.

If that is not possible, I'm happy with just creating a new window every time. Maybe it can be detected if a process is running in the current active window, and if not, using `cd` to switch the directory?

If anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1150431/432690

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This looks promising. I'll see if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @KamilMaciorowski pointed out, a very similar problem was solved by them [here](https://superuser.com/a/1492852/503699). I modified the script a little bit to suit my needs i.e. I want to ignore "busy" panes i.e. that have some program running on them, for which I check if the `#{pane_current_command}` is a known shell. Also, I don't pass an argument and just try to open the current directory as that is what I have to work with when running from `alacritty`.

Otherwise, it's just a rewrite of their script. The following is what I ended up using:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

target_path="$(pwd -P)"

tmux list-panes -s -F '#{window_id} #{pane_id} #{pane_current_path} #{pane_current_command}' \
| while IFS=' ' read -r window pane path cmd; do
    [[ "$path" = "$target_path" && " fish bash zsh " =~ " $cmd " ]] \
        && tmux select-pane -t "$pane" && tmux select-window -t "$window" && exit 0
done || tmux new-window -c "$target_path"

tmux attach -d
```